# How to convert character type to a datetime type in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sizable .csv file and the data types of the columns need to be changed. They are currently character type. Column "started_at" is below:

```
$ started_at         <chr> "4/26/20 17:45", "4/17/20 17:08", "4/1/20 17:54…
```

Summary:
started_at
Length:3353381
Class:character
Mode:character

I need to convert this to datetime and have tried: I've tried:

```
mutate(started_at = ymd_hms(as_datetime(started_at))
```

and

all_trips4 = all_trips3 %>%
mutate(
started_at = mdy_hm("%m/%d/%Y% %H:%M"))

and I keep getting warnings such as and I get NAs down the whole column:

> Warning: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone '%y/%m/%d'

I also need to change this column to numeric:

```
$ ride_length        <chr> "0:27:00", "0:09:00"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ymd_hms` isn't going to work unless the format is year, month, day, hour, minute, second. Your examples seem to be month/day/year hour:minute.

So try `mdy_hm` instead. Showing just for one value here, but you would use `dplyr::mutate`:

```
library(lubridate)
mdy_hm("4/26/20 17:45")

[1] "2020-04-26 17:45:00 UTC"
```

The second question: I'm assuming `ride_length` is measured in hours, minutes and seconds. So try `hms`, then `as.numeric` converts to seconds:

```
as.numeric(hms("0:27:00"))

[1] 1620
```

**EDIT** - your comments indicate that you are applying the code incorrectly to your data frame.

To be more explicit:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.frame(started_at = c("4/26/20 17:45"),
                  ended_at = c("4/26/20 18:12"),
                  run_length = c("0:27:00"))

df1

     started_at      ended_at run_length
1 4/26/20 17:45 4/26/20 18:12    0:27:00

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(started_at = mdy_hm(started_at), 
  ended_at = mdy_hm(ended_at), 
  run_length = as.numeric(hms(run_length)))

df1

           started_at            ended_at run_length
1 2020-04-26 17:45:00 2020-04-26 18:12:00       1620
```

Comment: Hi, the column $ started_at         <chr> "4/26/20 17:45" is just one row of data, I have thousands of rows of the date and time. How would i convert the entire column of "started_at" to datetime? I get NAs and timezone conflicts. I've tried  mutate(
    started_at = mdy_hm(started_at))  and the error is:    Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone '%y/%m/%d'

Comment: dplyr `mutate` should work. You're seeing a warning, not an error, and it's difficult to know why without seeing the full code and some example data which generates the warning. `mdy_hm` uses UTC by default unless you specify a timezone with the `tz=` option, see `?mdy_hm`.

Comment: all_trips4 = all_trips3 %>% 
   mutate(
     started_at = mdy_hm(all_trips3$started_at))          Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone '%y/%m/%d'  ----     I get NAs down the whole column

Comment: Please edit your question to show some example data from `all_trips3`. Also, you do not need to use the `$` operator in `mutate` - just `mutate(started_at = mdy_hm(started_at))` should work - and there's probably no need to create a new data frame either.